# Android:Java Interface: Imageview

Tags: android

I have encoded image in string.I want set src in html.it possible .My code to set text here!!!

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       String javascript = "javascript:(function()     {document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello'})()";
 view.loadUrl(javascript);
    }
});
refreshWebView();
return view;
}
 private void refreshWebView() {
 mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
refreshWebView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yoursign==encoded image :

when it pass

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
       mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   String javascript = "javascript:(function()     {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello'+
   "document.getElementById('managersig').src = '"               +"data:image/png;base64,"+yoursign + "';" +

  })()";
view.loadUrl(javascript);
}
 });
    refreshWebView();
   return view;
   }
```